# Can I use command substitution in git bash?

Tags: bash, openssl, git-bash

I love Git Bash because it puts all the powerful tools on a CLI for windows.  I'm trying to use it with `openssl` to generate a csr and key at the same time.  And, I'd like to do it all in one command.  Here's what I have so far:

```sh
openssl req -new -sha256 \
    -newkey ec:<(openssl ecparam -name prime256v1) -keyout site.key \
    -batch -out site.csr -utf8 \
    -subj '//C=US\ST=State\L=City\O=organization\OU=org unit\CN=site.com\emailAddress=admin@site.com' \
    -addext 'subjectAltName=DNS:site.com,DNS:www.site.com'
```

My problem is that `git bash` doesn't handle the command substitution properly (or I'm doing it wrong). When I run the above, I get

```
Can't open parameter file /dev/fd/63
15160:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72:fopen('/dev/fd/63','r')
15160:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79:
```

According to [the manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/req.html),

> All other algorithms support the **-newkey alg:file** form, where file may be an algorithm parameter file, created by the **genpkey -genparam** command...

so, I think I'm looking to feed it a file after `ec:`, I'm just not sure how. (btw, I took direction [from this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93712/200245). Although it's written for standard bash, I was hoping it would work.)